# Enviar instrucciones por linea de comandos

Tags: php

Tengo el achivo `print_pdf.bat` con los siguientes comandos

```
@echo off
D:
cd\
cd D:\wampserver\htdocs\pdf2printer\
PDFXCview.exe /printto "BIXOLON_SRP_280" Reporte.pdf
exit
```

es para enviar Reporte.pdf a la impresora por medio de PDFXCview.exe

desde PHP lo envio asi:

```
shell_exec("D:\wampserver\htdocs\pdf2printer\print_pdf.bat");
```

**Funciona Perfecto**, pero necesito pasarle las variables de "impresora" y el nombre del archivo .pdf, para lo cual omiti el .bat y utilice solo `shell_exec`, he intentado varias formas entre ellas esta que me parece que deberia funcionar pero no

```
$printer = "BIXOLON_SRP_280 ";
$file = "Reporte.pdf";

shell_exec("@echo off");
shell_exec("D:");
shell_exec("cd/");
shell_exec("cd D:/wampserver/htdocs/pdf2printer/");
shell_exec("PDFXCview.exe /printto " . $printer . $file);
shell_exec("exit");
```

si estoy usando la funcion correctamente? hay otras formas de hacerlo? tambien he probado con `exec` y `passthru`.

Comment: Pero tira algun error o que pasa? tambien sabes que le podes pasar variables al .bat no?

Comment: ¿Así no funciona? **`$output=null; shell_exec("D:\wampserver\htdocs\pdf2printer\print_pdf.bat $printer $file",$output);`** Supongo que las tienes bien definidas en el `.bat` ¿no?

Comment: No gbianchi, simplemente no muestra nada y no envia nada a la impresora, como enviaria las variables al .bat?

Comment: No  A. Cedano, pero si me muestra un warning
´Warning: shell_exec() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given in D:\wampserver\htdocs\1-alladin_AblePro\alladin\views\reports\adm_exec_bat.php on line 16´
en .bat esta como lo indico enla pregunta

Comment: Prueba usando `exec` de este modo:  `$file=escapeshellarg($file); $printer=escapeshellarg($printer); $output=exec("D:\wampserver\htdocs\pdf2printer\print_pdf.bat $file $printer");` y en el `.bat` defines dos variables así: `file=$1 printer=$2` para usarlas.

Answer (score 0):

Tengo que darle el credito a la orientacion de @A Cedano.

Finalmente logre que fucionara sin el .bat

```
$printer = "BIXOLON_SRP_280";
$file = "Reporte.pdf";

$output = exec("D:");
$output = exec("cd/");
$output = exec("cd D:/wampserver/htdocs/pdf2printer/");
$output = exec("PDFXCview.exe /printto $printer $file");
```